# Cancel/Modify Intent Message

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send a confirmation from the second activity to the main activity. If the checkbox is marked then I want to set `Intent` data and set the `Result` returned from activity to `true`.

Otherwise if the checkbox is unmarked then I want to either:

- Modify the intent that was set to false
- Remove the intent altogether as if it wasn't set

  ```
   ConfirmCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

          // Is the view now checked?
          boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

          if (checked) {
              Intent data = new Intent();
              data.putExtra(EXTRA_CONFIRM, true);
              setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
          }
          else
          {
              // Remove or modify to false.
          }
      }
  });
  ```

How can I do either of the actions to modify or cancel the Intent message? also, I would like to know what's the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the checkbox value as value for your Intent. There's no need to have this if/else construct.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_CONFIRM, true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

In your `MainActivity`'s `onActivityResult` you can simply check the Intents Extra for `EXTRA_CONFIRM` and decide how to react if the value is true/false.

Thats the basic approach to handle data sending between activities.
Further reading:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the extras using removeExtra() method and replace it using getIntent().replaceExtras()

Remove argument from intent:

```
  getIntent().removeExtra("search");
```

Replace bundle with new extras:

```
  Bundle extras = new Bundle();
  extras.putString("key","Value");
  getIntent().replaceExtras(extras);
```